# How do I properly size a table in Latex?

Tags: latex

This is my first Latex doc. Using Latex8.sty I'm trying to include a 5 column table. I've commented out everything but the introdution and the table. When I make the pdf it shows the introduction but no table. Any tips?

```
\begin{tabular}{|ll||l|c|r|rr}
 Mass&a1&a2&Fprime1&Fprime2\\
 \hline
 70g&0.988m/s^2&-2.79m/s^2&467.364N&424.02N\\
 80g&1.36m/s&-2.81m/s^2&3.84N&427.12N\\
 90g&1.70m/s^2&-2.74m/s^2&471.5N&416.48N\\
 100g&1.84m/s^2&-2.76m/s^2&491.12N&419.52N\\
 150g&3.11m/s^2&-2.88m/s^2&530.78N&437.76N\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example renders a correct-looking table. Notice the '$' around "m/s^2" (I dont know how it worked at all for you without those).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|ll||l|c|r|rr}
 Mass&a1&a2&Fprime1&Fprime2\\
 \hline
 70g&$0.988m/s^2$&$-2.79m/s^2$&467.364N&424.02N\\
 80g&$1.36m/s$&$-2.81m/s^2$&3.84N&427.12N\\
 150g&$3.11m/s^2$&$-2.88m/s^2$&530.78N&437.76N\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve the appearance of your table, you might also look at the [booktabs package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/).

To generate your table with the booktabs package, use the same tabular environment, but add \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for prettier tables
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|ll||l|c|r|rr}
\toprule
 Mass&a1&a2&Fprime1&Fprime2\\
\midrule
 70g&$0.988m/s^2$&$-2.79m/s^2$&467.364N&424.02N\\
 80g&$1.36m/s$&$-2.81m/s^2$&3.84N&427.12N\\
 150g&$3.11m/s^2$&$-2.88m/s^2$&530.78N&437.76N\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Read through the [booktabs documentation](http://ctan.org/get/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) for a short discussion about how tables should look (according to the author, at least).

If you want to be even more pedantic, you might also look at the [units package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/units/) for typesetting the units.  You could set the header of your table to:

```
Mass & $a_1$ & $a_2$ & $F'$ & $F''$ \\
```

unless you need to keep the variable names spelled out.

Comment: You definitely want to look at the siunitx package, which supercedes units (among other packages).